# How to set Specific Input Language for Single textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am creating a web application where in Customer registration page  ,for Customer Name input language should be arabic and for other fields it should be English.
I have tried with changing font of the textbox but when I am trying to save this its saving in English .I want to do this only using server side code.

is there any solution ?

Comment: I suggest you read up on HTML and its localisation and language features. All asp.net does is create HTML that the browser then renders. the data passed back to your asp.net code is just data and it has no idea about language, just character encoding.

Comment: Text boxes don't have a specific language. They just hold the input of whatever the user types in them. It all comes down to the encoding used when sending the information to the server.